# Join two tables and display distinct list of column

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have three tables.

1. Candidates

[image]

2. Skills

   [image]
3. CandidateToSkillMap

   [image]

**Candidate** and **Skill** tables are mapped in **CandidateToSkillMap** table. In that candidate_id and skill_id are foreign keys.

**How can i get following output with them ?**

Assume i need to display Computer Skills of candidate_id = 1

> Computer Skills -
>
> - MS Word (x)
> - MS Excel (x)
> - MS Paint ()

It should display distinct list of all available computer skills and there should be a check-box in-front. It will be checked if specific candidate has that skill.

EDIT -

I have query database and loaded data into arrays -

**$candidate_profile_computer_skills**

*this array gives all the computer skills*

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(Candidate\Model\CandidateProfileSkill)[317]
      public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'skill_name' => string 'MS Word' (length=7)
      public 'candidate_id' => null
      public 'candidateprofileskill_id' => null
  1 => 
    object(Candidate\Model\CandidateProfileSkill)[223]
      public 'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'skill_name' => string 'MS Excel' (length=8)
      public 'candidate_id' => null
      public 'candidateprofileskill_id' => null
  2 => 
    object(Candidate\Model\CandidateProfileSkill)[316]
      public 'id' => string '6' (length=1)
      public 'skill_name' => string 'MS Paint' (length=8)
      public 'candidate_id' => null
      public 'candidateprofileskill_id' => null
```

**$candidate_profile_skills_map**

*this array returns Skills and CandidateToSkillMap with LEFT JOIN for specific candidate (candidate_id = 1)*

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    object(Candidate\Model\CandidateProfileSkill)[321]
      public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'skill_name' => string 'MS Word' (length=7)
      public 'candidate_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'candidateprofileskill_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(Candidate\Model\CandidateProfileSkill)[322]
      public 'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'skill_name' => string 'Sinhala Reading' (length=15)
      public 'candidate_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'candidateprofileskill_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => 
    object(Candidate\Model\CandidateProfileSkill)[323]
      public 'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'skill_name' => string 'MS Excel' (length=8)
      public 'candidate_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'candidateprofileskill_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => 
    object(Candidate\Model\CandidateProfileSkill)[324]
      public 'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      public 'skill_name' => string 'English Reading' (length=15)
      public 'candidate_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'candidateprofileskill_id' => string '4' (length=1)
  4 => 
    object(Candidate\Model\CandidateProfileSkill)[325]
      public 'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      public 'skill_name' => string 'English Reading' (length=15)
      public 'candidate_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'candidateprofileskill_id' => string '4' (length=1)
```

Comment: Show us the code you've written so far.

Answer (score 0):

A join will do:

```
SELECT
    s.skill_name,
    CASE WHEN c.candidate_id IS NOT NULL THEN '(X)' ELSE '()' END has_skill
FROM
    skills s
    LEFT JOIN CandidateToSkillMap c ON s.skill_id = c.skill_id
WHERE
    c.candidate_id = 1
```

If it joins the right side successfully and thus `c.candidate_id` will be not null, then it means the person has that skill and you mark it else - don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this

`Select S.SkillName, count(*) from CandidateToSkillMap CTS, Skills S where S.Id = CTS.CandidateProfileSkillId group by CV.Id having CTS.CandidateId = 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM [Skills] s
LEFT JOIN [CandidateToSkillMap] csm ON csm.candidateprofileskill_id = s.id
WHERE csm.candidate_id = 1
```

This will return all rows from the skills table, and you can do a null-check on the column "candidate_id" to ascertain whether or not the candidate in question has the skill on that row.

Here's some pseudo:

```
for($row in $result) { 
    Skill name: $row["skill_name"]
    Has skill?: $row["candidate_id"] != null ? "Yes" : "No"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
select S.skill_name from CandidateToSkillMap CSM, Skills s where  S.id=CSM.candidatesprofileskill_id and CSM.candidate_id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
SELECT s.skill_name, (cm.Candidate_id IS NOT NULL) AS HasSkill

FROM Skills AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN candidateToSkillMap AS cm
ON s.id = cm.candidateprofileskill_id
WHERE s.skill_type = 'Computer Literacy'
AND (Candidate_id = 1 OR Candidate_id IS NULL)
```

The above query uses `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to join the `skills` and `candidatestoskillmap` include all the rows from skills tables.  This will ensure that any rows not matched in the `candidatestoskillmap` table are included as null values.

The `select` section then looks for these values and assigns a true/false for it.

The `Where` section filters for the skill type and the candidate's id.